# Getting key-value from Object in Java

Tags: java, hash-map

This takes a collection of `Object`s from JavaScript and puts them into a Java project. How can I improve this code? What's the best solution?

```
// JavaScript fetch data into List ChartData

int i = 0;
int k = 0;

// output
for (Object currObj : ChartData) {

    // get all fields of Object
    for (Field field : currObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

        field.setAccessible(true); 
        Object value = field.get(currObj); 
         // parse only HashMap
        if ((value != null)&&value.getClass().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("class        java.util.HashMap"))) {

            //get HashMap
            HashMap hm = (HashMap)value;
            // Get a set of the entries
            Set set = hm.entrySet();
            // Get an iterator
            Iterator j = set.iterator();

            // Display elements
            while(j.hasNext()) {
               Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)j.next();
               if ((me.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))){
                 assertTrue(Long.parseLong(me.getValue().toString()) == anArrayOfObjects[i][0]); // check pairs                                
                 System.out.println("Actual y value - " + me.getValue().toString() + " expected value - " + anArrayOfObjects[k][0].toString());
                 i++;  
               }

               if ((me.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("x"))){
                  assertTrue(Long.parseLong(me.getValue().toString()) == anArrayOfObjects[k][1]);// check pairs 
                  System.out.println("Actual x value - " + me.getValue().toString() + " expected value - " + anArrayOfObjects[k][1].toString());
                  k++;
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Naming Convention

It is common practice and part of the SUN / Oracle Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language to start variable names with lowercase.
Thus, you might want to rename `ChartData` to `chartData`.

Oh, and `j` is *not* an acceptable name for an `Iterator`.
A few lines down, I can no longer remember what `j` was.
Usually, `j` is an `int` and used because `i` was used already.
And in fact you already do have an `int i`.

In such a case, name the `Iterator` `it` or `iter` or even `iterator` but not `j`.

Also, the name `me` for `Map.Entry` is a bit confusing, because the abbreviation `me` is a valid English word at the same time.
I'd rename `me` to `entry`.

### Iterating over `Map` entries

Your code for iterating over the map entries is too complex.

Here's the relevant part of your code:

```
HashMap hm = (HashMap) value; // context
Set set = hm.entrySet();
Iterator j = set.iterator();
while (j.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) j.next();
    // Do something with me.
}
```

You can remove the cast by telling the `Set` and the `Iterator` that they are from a `Map`, which means they are a `Set<Map.Entry>` and an `Iterator<Map.Entry>`.
This simplifies the code as follows:

```
HashMap hm = (HashMap) value; // context
Set<Map.Entry> set = hm.entrySet();
Iterator<Map.Entry> j = set.iterator();
while (j.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry me = j.next();
    // Do something with me.
}
```

You can further simplify this by turning this into a `for`-each loop:

```
HashMap hm = (HashMap) value; // context
for (Map.Entry me : hm.entrySet()) {
    // Do something with me.
}
```

### Abstract datatypes

Whether your map is a `HashMap` or something else is probably irrelevant.
Therefore you might want to change the datatype of variable `hm` from `HashMap` to `Map`.

```
Map hm = (Map) value;
```

### How to check types

Java has an `instanceof` operator.

Your type check compares the `toString()` result of the class.
That has a few issues.

- Your comparison relies on a specific format of `Class.toString()` which is not guaranteed. If you must compare the name, use `getName()` instead of `toString()`.
- Your comparison is case-insensitive, which is definitely the wrong thing to do in a case-sensitive language. `java.util.HashMap` and `java.util.hashmap` could in theory both exist but would be separate classes. Your code would treat `java.util.hashmap` as if it were the same as `java.util.HashMap`, which is wrong.
- Your comparison checks on the `class`, ruling out possible subclasses of `HashMap` as well as alternative `Map` implementations. In a broader sense, you're violating the *LSP - Liskov Substitution Principle*.

You might want to go for this code to check the type:

```
Object value = field.get(currObj);
if (value instanceof HashMap) // ...
```

or even

```
Object value = field.get(currObj);
if (value instanceof Map) // ...
```

### Interlude: New source code as of now

```
for (Object currObj : chartData) {
    for (Field field : currObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(currObj);
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            Map hm = (Map) value;
            for (Map.Entry entry : hm.entrySet()) {
                if ((entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))) {
                    assertTrue(Long.parseLong(me.getValue().toString()) == anArrayOfObjects[i][0]); // check pairs
                    System.out.println("Actual y value - " + me.getValue().toString() + " expected value - " + anArrayOfObjects[k][0].toString());
                    i++;
                }

                if ((entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("x"))) {
                    assertTrue(Long.parseLong(me.getValue().toString()) == anArrayOfObjects[k][1]);// check pairs
                    System.out.println("Actual x value - " + me.getValue().toString() + " expected value - " + anArrayOfObjects[k][1].toString());
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Method length

This method is far too long to be even close to maintainable source code.
As software craftsmen, we say that regarding method length Java code is maintainable if (almost) all of its methods have 5 or fewer lines.
10 lines is something which I already do not accept in production code.
(Exceptions like some GUI creation code apply.)

The code should be split into several methods.
I know that you might even have tried this - and failed, due to the local variables `i` and `k`.

Let's remember what *Uncle Bob* said: "Long functions are where classes use to hide." and "Extract 'till you drop" (Robert C. Martin, "Clean Code")

### Refactorings to apply to get smaller methods

1. Extract method object.
2. Turn local variables `i` and `k` into fields and introduce getters for them (you wouldn't increment them if you wouldn't need them later).
3. Refactor the constructor argument into an argument to `invoke()`.
4. Rename `invoke` to `visit`.
5. Extract every multiline block into a separate method with a meaningful name.
6. Make the two branches for "x" and "y" look identical by replacing everything which is different with variables. For that piece of code which is different we use two methods implementing a functional interface Incrementor so we can store a method reference in a variable.

Here's how this looks like as a class:

```
private static class ChartDataVisitor {
    private int i = 0;
    private int k = 0;

    public void visit(Iterable<Object> chartData) throws IllegalAccessException {
        reset();
        visitChartData(chartData);
    }

    private void reset() {
        i = 0;
        k = 0;
    }

    private void visitChartData(Iterable<Object> chartData) throws IllegalAccessException {
        for (Object currObj : chartData) visitObject(currObj);
    }

    private void visitObject(Object currObj) throws IllegalAccessException {
        for (Field field : currObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) visitField(currObj, field);
    }

    private void visitField(Object currObj, Field field) throws IllegalAccessException {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(currObj);
        if (value instanceof Map) visitMap((Map) value);
    }

    private void visitMap(Map<?, ?> hm) {
        hm.entrySet().forEach(this::visitEntry);
    }

    private void visitEntry(Map.Entry<?, ?> entry) {
        visitEntryDetails(entry, "y", i, 0, this::incrementI);
        visitEntryDetails(entry, "x", k, 1, this::incrementK);
    }

    private void visitEntryDetails(Map.Entry<?, ?> entry, String string, int index1, int index2, Incrementor incrementor) {
        if ((entry.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(string)))
            visitMatchingDetails(entry, string, index1, index2, incrementor);
    }

    private void visitMatchingDetails(Map.Entry<?, ?> entry, String string, int index1, int index2, Incrementor incrementor) {
        final String valueAsString = entry.getValue().toString();
        final Long v = anArrayOfObjects[index1][index2];
        assertTrue(Long.parseLong(valueAsString) == v); // check pairs
        System.out.println("Actual " + string + " value - " + valueAsString + " expected value - " + v.toString());
        incrementor.increment();
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private static interface Incrementor {
        void increment();
    }

    private void incrementK() {
        k++;
    }

    private void incrementI() {
        i++;
    }
}
```

You might notice that not a single method contains `{}` inside.
That's the whole point.
`{}` are an opportunity to extract.
Good methods do one thing, they do it well and they do it only.
By having `{}` inside, you loudly declare that your method is doing more than one thing (or in case of `try` that the language Java is inconsistent because otherwise it would allow for a `try` or `catch` or `finally` without braces).

You're of course free to reformat it to bring back the removed `{}`, if you like or if there are militant "{}-Pros" around you (I was one of them myself once, not so long ago).
Today I tend to avoid `{}` to show off "Look Ma, no `{}`!" - I don't need them anymore.

### Unit Testing

The methods in the new class do not need to be `private`.
They could as well be package default or `public`, depending on your business logic.
Because they need not be `private`, you can easily unit test them individually - you can now test your business logic from inside to the out.
The various layers that were already there (nested block structure in your code) have become accessible individually.
Think of an Onion or Matryoshka.

### Warning

My names `visit*` and similar are not very meaningful. They are physical names. I couldn't come up with better names because I have no idea about what your code is doing. I don't know what the map contains.

You should change some or even all of the the `visit*` method names to something which communicates the intent of your business logic much better.

Comment: I thought this was a pretty good answer except for the part "You might notice that not a single method contains `{}` inside". Come on, that's stretching things too far, and you're playing cheat too with one-liner `for` loops and `if` statements. :p There's nothing inherently wrong with a couple of `{ }` pairs, it's only a problem when you start to having something like 5 `if-else-ifs` with 3 `for` loops at each branch doing *very similar* things. For more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

Comment: Whether the `if` and `for` are one-liners or two-liners doesn't matter. What matters is that each method does one thing, it does it well and it does it only. My methods are so simple that they do not need braces. Yes, Cyclomatic Complexity - feel free to run my code through a metrics tool and you will see that each method has a McCabe Cyclomatic Complexity of at max 2. A couple of `{}` pairs is required if your method is too complex. You'll add braces, fine, it's your code, I'll rather extract more methods, with greetings to the Bee Gees and Robert C. Martin :)